# Difference Between session.evict vs clear

Tags: hibernate

what is difference between session.clear and evict methods in hibernate.Both are detatched objects that is instance removed from session.when should i use session.clear and session.evict in hibernate.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[evict()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict%28java.lang.Object%29) evicts a single object from the session. [clear()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#clear%28%29) evicts all the objects in the session. Calling clear() is like calling evict() on every object associated with the session.